# How to prevent contextual-links from being styled?

Tags: theming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to override contextual styles?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/58971/how-to-override-contextual-styles)

The contextual-links seem to be picking up the styles from the block they belong to. How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: It's probably easier to add CSS to style them the way you want rather than to remove the styling.  That's why CSS operates as a cascade, after all.

Comment: Thanks I am trying to override the styles that are coming from the contextual module. Should I copy the css to my theme? Or in the sites/all/modules/contextual directory?

Comment: To override styles, you should do it in your theme.  It is considered best practice to never touch contrib module files; instead, overrides should be handled by your theme or a custom module (this makes upgrades easier).  I would explain in more detail but overriding CSS styles is a basic  (non-Drupal) web design topic that is out of scope for this site.